# XSLT: Iterating through all value of a xsl:key map

Tags: xslt

**XML**

```
<books>
  <book title="XML Today" author="David Perry" release="2016"/>
  <book title="XML and Microsoft" author="David Perry" release="2015"/>
  <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim" release="2015"/>
</books>
```

The following XSL code iterates through all books by *David Perry*.

**XSL**

```
<xsl:key name="title-search" match="book" use="@author"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <HTML>
      <BODY>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('title-search', 'David Perry')">
         <DIV>
         <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
         </DIV>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </BODY>
   </HTML>
</xsl:template>
```

**HTML output**

```
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <DIV>XML Today</DIV>
    <DIV>XML and Microsoft</DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now I would like to iterate not only through all books by *David Perry* but through all books by any author.
How would a corresponding outer loop look like? 
Or in other words: How do I iterate through all values of my *title-search* key.

The output should be something like this:

```
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <H1>David Perry</H1>
    <DIV>XML Today</DIV>
    <DIV>XML and Microsoft</DIV>
    <H1>Jim Kim</H1>
    <DIV>XML Productivity</DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="title-search" match="book" use="@author"/>

    <xsl:template match="/books">
        <HTML>
            <BODY>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="book" />
            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:variable name="author" select="@author" />
        <xsl:if test="generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('title-search', $author)[1])">
            <H1><xsl:value-of select="@author" /></H1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//book[@author = $author]" mode="titles"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book" mode="titles">
        <DIV>
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        </DIV>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It uses a technique called Muenchian grouping. Each element in an XML document implicitly has a unique ID assigned to it by the XSLT processor (it can also be explicitly assigned with the id attribute in the document itself). This part:

```
generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('title-search', $author)[1])
```

basically tests if the ID of the current book element is the same as that of the first book element with the same author. The variable `$author` is taken from the current book, The key is used to look up the `<book>` elements with that same author, the `[1]` predicate takes the first one. As a result, the `<H1>` is only generated for the first occurrence of that specific author, and in that same `if` element we're then applying the template for listing the books of that author. The mode is used to avoid a clash between these templates. There's no doubt a solution that doesn't use modes, but this works too. You could also do a lot of this with `<xsl:for-each>` but I made separate templates because XSLT is declarative and works best when treating it as such.

Grouping is a lot easier in XSLT 2, but when stuck with XSLT 1, the Muenchian grouping technique often provides a solution once you grok it.

Comment: I found a solution in the mean time which is similar to Rudramuni TP's `preceding` based approach. So which approach is better? Muenchian groupings or `preceding`?

Comment: @Lugaxx If both produce the right output for all possible input document scenarios, it would be best to go with what has the best performance in terms of execution time and memory use. These differences might be negligible for small inputs, but more pronounced for large documents. It's kind of hard to predict performance differences between both approaches and some of it would depend on the XSLT processor internals, so maybe try both with the largest XML you expect to see and choose the best performing one.

Comment: @Lugaxx, G_H's answer is perfect one, consider that.

Comment: Actually, I have to transform the XML code into JSON. Therefore, I need to skip the comma (,) behind the last element. I know how to do it using `for-each` (Rudramuni TP's approach). But how would you do that using the Muenchian grouping technique?

Comment: @Lugaxx Output the comma within an xsl:if conditional. You could use the generate-id trick again to see if the book is the last one for its author, like so: `<xsl:if test="generate-id(.) != generate-id(//book[@author = $author][last()])">`. You would need to fill the author variable again in the book template, or pass it on from the other one as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**XSLT2:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <HTML>
    <BODY>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="books/book" group-by="@author">
            <H1><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></H1>
             <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
               <DIV><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></DIV>
             </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XSLT 1 idea could work, but this implementation behaves incorrectly when books from the same author aren't all in a single run in the input document. For example, having a book by author a, then author b, then a again would incorrectly list the third book under author b.